# How is the Overflow AI VS Code extension going to compete with the GitHub Copilot Chat extension?

Tags: support, company, overflowai

(When I say "you" in this post, I am addressing the Stack Exchange company)

The GitHub Copilot Chat extension already provides "agents" one can chat with to understand a project. And the features will keep improving. See [1.84 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_84#_chat-agents), [1.85 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_github-copilot). It has features to [generate test cases](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/github-copilot-chat/about-github-copilot-chat#generating-unit-test-cases), [explain code](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/github-copilot-chat/about-github-copilot-chat#explaining-code), [propose code fixes](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/github-copilot-chat/about-github-copilot-chat#proposing-code-fixes), and [coding questions](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/github-copilot-chat/about-github-copilot-chat#answering-coding-questions).

I'm concerned with the value of the way that the company is spending time and money- especially considering what we've seen with [the costs of pursuing AI](/q/393806/997587). You're literally competing against the company that holds the keys for VS Code itself and [its extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api), and what goes in the [bleeding](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/src/vscode-dts) [edge](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api) of that API. And the OverflowAI VS Code extension hasn't even released yet, whereas GitHub Copilot Chat is out there getting user buy-in.

How is the OverflowAI VS Code extension going to compete?

- Will it be cheaper? In what ways/scenarios and for who?
- Will it have any *unique*, high-value features?
- Will it do the same job(s) better? All I've heard is that it will explain code snippets, which is just one of several of GitHub Copilot Chat's features.
- Will the underlying machine learning models be "better"? Concretely, how/why?
- Will it be more ethical? How so? And if it will be, how much weight do you realistically expect that to have on what choice consumers make?
- Will you have more bandwidth to listen to your users and address their feedback? To be quite frank, that does not seem to be your strong suit, and you've shown that you're tight on staff, and you're no super big, super rich company like Microsoft.

Comment: While that are all interesting questions, I would still say that they are a bit off-topic and not really about the software that powers this platform here or do I oversee something and there is a connection to Overflow AI VS Code extension? It's also a bit wanting too much. Who knows what the future will bring. I think they are free to burn their money any way they like and more competition is always better. On the other hand, is there a dedicated community for Overflow AI products? Or is this supposed to happen here?

Comment: More suited to Meta SO perhaps.

Comment: and Github CoPilot may be bundled with MS products in future, Office, Azure...

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic here. Based on my (still limited) experiences with it, GitHub Copilot appears to possibly be trained on other topics related to software development found on other Stack Exchange sites, such as Software Engineering, Database Administrators, Code Review, and more. In addition to these questions, I'd want to know if there are plans to train SO's product on these other sites as well. And, if not, I'd want to understand the harm that comes with not only not training, but blocking these tools from consuming other network sites and effectively cutting off access.